# How to bind entity with createNamedBuilder()?

Tags: php, symfony

I need to have two different forms (but using the same entity) on one page. To do so, I used `createNamedBuilder()`:

```
$cover = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('cover')
    ->add('file')
    ->getForm();

$data = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('data')
    ->add('name','text')
    ->getForm();
```

My problem is, how can I bind my entity to it? When I use `createFormBuilder()` it goes like

```
$game = new Game;
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($game);
```

If I try to use `createFormBuilder` like this:

```
    $cover = $this->createFormBuilder($game)
        ->add('file')
        ->getForm();

    $data = $this->createFormBuilder($game)
        ->add('name')
        ->getForm();
```

Using the secound form results in "This form should not contain extra fields." notice.

Comment: What is the purpose of each form?

Comment: It can be used in a lot of situations, especially when you want to ommit too much "click here to" links, eg. you can eithr log in or register on one page. Here, I want to use image uploading and inserting in database separately, so the user would see the image BEFORE the whole thing would go in to the DB.

Comment: For using `createFormBuilder`, are you trying to bind the form when no data is passed to it? Can you post more of your controller code?

Comment: Actually have you tried multi-step forms? [This bundle](https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle/) seems to do what you want pretty well.

Comment: I'll propably have to do something on my own. Squazic's bundle is a little too much for my purposes right now.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the API docs](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.html#method_createNamedBuilder), the third parameter of `createNamedBuilder` can be used to pass in an entity.

Your code should look like this:

```
$game = new Game;

$cover = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('cover', 'form', $game)
    ->add('file')
    ->getForm();

$data = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('data', 'form', $game)
    ->add('name','text')
    ->getForm();
```

(Note that the position of the first and second parameters are swapped if you happen to still be using Symfony 2.0.)

Answer (score 2):

In Symfony 2.8/3.0 this has changed a bit and if you have a form that you want to bind other entities to then see my answer here:

[Passing data to buildForm() in Symfony 2.8/3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027711/passing-data-to-buildform-in-symfony-2-8-3-0/34159802#34159802)

In case anyone is using a `createNamedBuilder` or `createNamed` functions from `form.factory` service here's the snippet on how to set and save the data using it. You cannot use the `data` field (leave that null) and you have to set the passed **data/entities** as `$options` value.

I also incorporated **@sarahg** instructions about using `setAllowedTypes()` and `setRequired()` options and it seems to work fine but you first need to define field with `setDefined()`

Also inside the form if you need the data to be set remember to add it to `data` field.

In Controller I am using `getBlockPrefix` as `getName` was deprecated in **2.8/3.0**

**Controller**

```
/*
* @var $builder Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface
*/

$formTicket = $this->get('form.factory')->
              createNamed(
                  $tasksPerformedForm->getBlockPrefix(),
                  TaskAddToTicket::class,
                  null,
                  array(
                      'ticket' => $ticket
                  )
              );
```

**Form**

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)    {
    $resolver->setDefined('ticket');
    $resolver->setRequired('ticket');
    $resolver->addAllowedTypes('ticket', Ticket::class);

    $resolver->setDefaults(array(           
        'translation_domain'=>'AcmeForm',
        'validation_groups'=>array('validation_group_001'),
        'tasks' => null,
        'ticket' => null,
    ));
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)   {

    $this->setTicket($options['ticket']);
    //This is required to set data inside the form!
    $options['data']['ticket']=$options['ticket'];

    $builder

        ->add('ticket',  HiddenType::class, array(
                'data_class'=>'acme\TicketBundle\Entity\Ticket',
            )
        )
...
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @IKavanagh I added the whole answer below the link. But it's not DRY to do that that's why I posted a link only.