# How to pass parameter to FormType constructor from controller

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

In Symfony2.7 i was able to pass parameter to Form Type constructor directly from controller while creating the form, however in Symfony3 i'm not able to do it!

**Before in Symfony2.7**

```
$postedBy = $this->getUser()->getFullname();
$form = $this->createForm(new NewsType($postedBy));
```

**After in Symfony3**

```
$form = $this->createForm(NewsType::class); // no idea how to pass parameter?
```

**Update:**
I also wanted to access it from:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    // how to access posted_by_name here which is sent from controller
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated..

Comment: Thank for your help, i resolved it myself, please check my answer..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data to buildForm() in Symfony 2.8/3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027711/passing-data-to-buildform-in-symfony-2-8-3-0)

Comment: @jonathan - Answers to that question does't fully answer my question! as updated in my answer, I needed passed parameters in form event listeners as well..

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Thanks for your time! i resolved this myself:

I removed parameter from NewsType constructor and added data to postedBy form field using $options array, and passed data to $options array from controller, please check following:

**NewsType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('postedBy', HiddenType::class, array(
            'data' => $options['postedBy']
          )
        )
    ;
}

// WARNING: this is a MANDATORY block! Only options described here will be allowed to be passed.
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'postedBy' => null,
    ));
}
```

**Controller**

```
$form = $this->createForm(NewsType::class, $news, array(
    'postedBy' => $this->getUser()->getFullname(),
);
```

**UPDATE:**
Please use below code if you want to access $options array from addEventListener:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $postedBy = $event->getForm()->getConfig()->getOptions()['postedBy'];
}
```

Hope it helps somebody!

Comment: Or use:

`$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($options) { $postedBy = $options['postedBy']; }`

Answer (score 14):

You need to define your [form as service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-as-services).

```php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use App\Utility\MyCustomService;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class NewsType extends AbstractType
{
    private $myCustomService;

    private $myStringParameter;

    public function __construct(MyCustomService $service, $stringParameter)
    {
        $this->myCustomService   = $service;
        $this->myStringParameter = $stringParameter;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Add to your service configuration:

```yaml
#src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    app.form.type.task:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\NewsType
        arguments:
            - "@app.my_service"
            - "posted_by_name"
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

Comment: That's a good idea however i needed a solution that could be done from Controller + Form Type..

Comment: To me, this feels like a workaround. Passing options using 'OptionsResolver' looks like a good practise. Or am I wrong?

Comment: It resolves said issue very well.. and that's what i wanted :)

Comment: jkucharovic has the correct answer. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service states that as well

Comment: yes that is correct solution too but i did't need to create a separate service in my situation..

Answer (score 13):

#### You are both right.

@Muzafar and @jkucharovic, the question is when to use which...

As Bernard Schussek shows in [Symfony Forms 101](https://speakerdeck.com/webmozart/symfony-forms-101):

<kbd>1</kbd> Don't pass **Dynamic Data** to constructor..

[image]

<kbd>2</kbd> ... but use **Custom Options** instead

[image]

<kbd>3</kbd> Do pass **Global Settings** to constructor (or services)

[image]

[image]