# Passing arguments from controller to form type __construct in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-3.3

In Symfony2 we used:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType($mySession));
```

We can pass $session as an arguments in __construct.

But I'm not able to pass $session argument in Symfony3

I have tried something like this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(MyFormType::class, array(
        'mySession' => $mySession
    ));
```

Can anyone please guide me? How to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass parameter to FormType constructor from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905490/how-to-pass-parameter-to-formtype-constructor-from-controller)

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd argument for createForm method is the $datas you set. You can link the data to an entity using data_class in the FormType configureOptions like this :

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => MyEntity::class,
    ));
}
```

Also, Symfony accepts a third parameter for options
Here's the core methods :

```
/**
     * Creates and returns a Form instance from the type of the form.
     *
     * @param string $type    The fully qualified class name of the form type
     * @param mixed  $data    The initial data for the form
     * @param array  $options Options for the form
     *
     * @return Form
     */
    protected function createForm($type, $data = null, array $options = array())
    {
        return $this->container->get('form.factory')->create($type, $data, $options);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this link help you:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $this->yourVarableName = $options['yourVarableName']; // here you will catch your pass data

    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ...
        ->add('your_field_type', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Label Field',
            'mapped' => false,
            'choices' => $this->traitChoices['figure_type']
        ))
        ...
    ;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Foo\YouBundle\Entity\Goal',
        'yourVarableName' => null, // here your data
    ));
}
```

When creating the form your controller:

```
$goal = new Goal(); //instance of Entity
$form = $this->createForm(GoalType::class, $goal, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('profile_update'),
        'method' => 'PUT',
        'yourVarableName' => $yourVarableName,
    ));
```

Comment: where we have to defined "$profile" 
I'm newer to symfony3, so It will be better to explain with an example.
Thanks

Comment: @mobizen Do you undestand?

Comment: Yes, I have make changes as you told me...
But getting same error "Type error: Too few arguments to function FD\PatientBundle\Form\GoalType::__construct(), 0 passed"

Comment: @mobizen You need to remove the constructor from GoalType.  For all intents and purposes, S3 no longer allows using the constructor.  (Well, in theory you could define your form type as a service but that's another story).