# Passing data to buildForm() in Symfony 3.3

Tags: php, symfony, arguments

i'm trying to pass current authenticated user to buildForm for the pass couple of hours, i searched google ... nothing worked
the error i'm getting is

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class AppBundle\Entity\AdsList, but is a(n) array. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) array to an instance of AppBundle\Entity\AdsList.

on `->getForm();`

i have to ideea what to do ... a view transformer ... ( https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html )

but i only have an integer ...

i also want to generate unique slugs from the content ( final version wont have a title field ) if you have a good example :)

thanks in advance :)

**AgencyController.php**

```
/**
 * @Route("/agency/post", name="agency_post")
 */
public function agencyNewAd(Request $request)
{
   //  $agency = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser(); ( this didn't worked .. )
    $form = $this->createForm(AgencyNewAdType::class, array(
        'postedBy' => $this->getUser(),
    ));
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $ad = $form->getData();

        // save the task to the database
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($ad);
        $em->flush();
        // return new Response('Saved new Post with id ' . $ad->getId());
        return $this->redirectToRoute('agency_admin');
    }
    return $this->render('agency/new_ad.html.twig', [
        'adForm' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

**AgencyNewAdType.php**

```
class AgencyNewAdType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905490/how-to-pass-parameter-to-formtype-constructor-from-controller
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class)
        ->add('content', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('category', EntityType::class, array(
            // query choices from Category.Name
            'class' => 'AppBundle:CategoryAd',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
        ))
        ->add('postedAt', DateType::class)
        ->add('postedBy',HiddenType::class, array(
            'data' => $options['postedBy']
        ))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Post'))
        ->getForm();

}
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
   {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'postedBy' => null,
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\AdsList',
    ));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i needed to pass the argument to the form so it would look like

```
public function agencyNewAd(Request $request): Response
{
    $pass = new AdsList();
    $pass->setPostedBy($this->getUser());
    $form = $this->createForm(AgencyNewAdType::class, $pass);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // $form->getData() holds the submitted values iN MeM
        $ad = $form->getData();

        // save the ad to the database
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($ad);
        $em->flush();
        // return new Response('Saved new Post with id ' . $ad->getId());
        return $this->redirectToRoute('agency_admin');
    }
    return $this->render('agency/new_ad.html.twig', [
        'adForm' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

and in the form i need to remove postedBy ...

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905490/how-to-pass-parameter-to-formtype-constructor-from-controller
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class)
        ->add('content', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('category', EntityType::class, array(
            // query choices from Category.Name
            'class' => 'AppBundle:CategoryAd',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
        ))
        ->add('postedAt', DateType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Post'))
        ->getForm();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a parameter when creating you from in a controller, 2nd parameter should be your object connected to the form and 3rd is the options array, so it would look like:

```
public function agencyNewAd(Request $request)
{
    $ad = new AdsList();
    $form = $this->createForm(AgencyNewAdType::class, $ad, array(
        'postedBy' => $this->getUser(),
    ));
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($ad);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('agency_admin');
    }
    return $this->render('agency/new_ad.html.twig', [
        'adForm' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

The alternative way is to pass your option to the construct of your form like this:

```
public function agencyNewAd(Request $request)
{
    $ad = new AdsList();
    $form = $this->createForm(new AgencyNewAdType($this->getUser()), $ad);
```

and then in your constructor of AgencyNewAdType you would accept your parameter, in this case currently logged in user.

Comment: for the first option i got a 10 pages error ->

`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Agency could not be converted to string").`

Comment: and for the second -> 
` Type error: Argument 3 passed to Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller::createForm() must be of the type array, object given, called in /home/dev/www/d/src/AppBundle/Controller/AgencyController.php on line 46`

line 46

` $form = $this->createForm(AgencyNewAdType::class,($this->getUser()), $ad);`

Comment: @AlexanderBr. the first error does not look connected to the form as I do not see you mentioned Agency Entity anywhere but I guess you need a toString method in that Entity

Comment: can you help me ?

Comment: @AlexanderBr. check my answer you have to do `$this->createForm(new AgencyNewAdType($this->getUser()), $ad);` So your form constructor is accepting the user entity and not second parameter

Comment: for the 2nd PHPstorm says ->

`Method call uses 1 parameters, but method signature uses 0 parameters less... (Ctrl+F1) 

Detects if function/method call uses more parameters than the declaration.  Options: 
Disable for functions/methods with last parameter $_ Ignores function with last parameter $_ in declaration
Disable for functions/methods with func_get_arg/func_get_args call Ignores functions with "func_get_arg", "func_get_args" calls inside`

there is a problem with this `AgencyNewAdType($this`

Comment: i have made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/cybernet/fd8d69dea4f22fb2012d2238bdf8dd63)

please help ( is my first week with symfony )

Comment: @AlexanderBr. do you know what a constructor is? if you pass parameter to an object as `new Object($param)` then your constructor has to accept it, Symfony is not your problem, you do not know OOP, try to read about that first

Comment: @AlexanderBr. check your gist, that should solve it for you

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE)
PHPstorm says

private $user; $user is undefined

$this->user Field 'user' not found in AgencyNewAdType less...
Referenced field is not found in subject class. Note: Check is not performed on objects of type "stdClass" or derived.