# PHP/Symfony 3: Use fully-qualified class name (string) to call instantiated class methods

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I originally had the following working code fragment in my controller class when trying to create a form in Symfony 2:

```
$formBuilder = new CustomType();
$formBuilder->setTTypes($types);
$formBuilder->setFList($list);

$form = $this->createForm($formBuilder, [
'List' => $id ]);

return $form->createView();
```

However, due to deprecations that needed to be fixed upon upgrading to Symfony 3 within forms (such as using the fully-qualified class name for form types), I get this error when the above code executes:

`Expected argument of type "string", "...\CustomBundle\Form\CustomType" given`

Switching the above code fragment to using the fully-qualified class name like so fixes the above error:

```
$formBuilder = CustomType::class;
//$formBuilder->setTTypes($types);
//$formBuilder->setFList($list);

$form = $this->createForm($formBuilder, [
'List' => $id ]);

return $form->createView();
```

But notice that I had to comment out the two functions within the CustomType class. Because if I don't, I get this error:

`FatalThrowableError
 Call to a member function setTTypes() on string`

I understand *why* I'm getting the error, I'm just not sure how to rewrite it so that I can use the fully-qualified class name (which is a string of the class path) and call those methods off of it.

I'm new to both Symfony and php, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Basically you can't.  Symfony no longer allows passing an instance of a FormType to createForm.  You might be able to pass $types and $list as options.  And yes, it was quite painful when this last minute change was made just as 2.7 was released.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `::class` you get the complete Path to the class. So you give the name to the class to the form builder. Direct passing of attributes isn't supported anymore. So if you need something in your form you have to build a class as service and inject them to the form.

[How to pass parameter to FormType constructor from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905490/how-to-pass-parameter-to-formtype-constructor-from-controller)

Here is a good example in the answer how to define a service and inject them to the form. So this can be a bit of pain when you have used it before.