# Symfony Form passing values from collection to form type

Tags: php, forms, symfony-forms, symfony

i have a collection type:

```
->add('tipi', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => TipiType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'mapped' => false,
                'entry_options' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => false,
                )
            ))
```

Extend this formtype:

```
 ->add('tipi', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Tipo',
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Tipi',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                    ->innerJoin('t.requests', 'r')
            ;
        },
            ))
    ;
```

In the first form type i have an options sended from controller in this way:

```
$idRequest = $request->get('id');
$form = $this->createForm(RequestsType::class, $requests, array('id_request' => $idRequest));
```

In the first i can used it but in the child FormType not.. I would passing this variable in the collection type..
Someone can help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal that you can't use the $options variable directly in the function because it's a closure and it encapsulates its scope, meaning that it has no access to the scope in which it is defined or executed. It is, however, possible to inherit variables from the parent scope (where the closure is defined) into the closure with the use keyword
so there's two way to solve your problem .

1 - Using the keyword "use"

```
       ->add('tipi', EntityType::class, array(
                        'label' => 'Tipo',
                        'class' => 'AppBundle:Tipi',
                        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
                        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                            ->innerJoin('t.requests', 'r')
                            ->where('r.id = idrequest')
                            ->setParameter('idrequest' ,$this->options['id_request']);
                    ;
// user your $options variable 
                },
                    ))
            ;
```

2- Try to create a local attribute in the form class and add a constructor to initiate it after that you can use freely your variable as bellow

```
class YourForm extends AbstractType
{
    private $options = array();

    public function __construct($options)
    {

       $this->options = $options;
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
->add('tipi', EntityType::class, array(
                        'label' => 'Tipo',
                        'class' => 'AppBundle:Tipi',
                        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
                        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er){
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                            ->innerJoin('t.requests', 'r')
                            ->where('r.id = idrequest')
                            ->setParameter('idrequest' ,$this->options['id_request']);
                    ;

                },
                    ))
            ;
}



// Controller 
        $form = $this->createForm(new YourForm($options), $class);
```

For Symfony 3

you should do it trough options resolver, add the following snippet in your form class

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'URL of your entity',
        'id_request' => null,
    ));
}
```

now the the $options['id_request'] will be available for use in your formBuilder

Hope that will help you.

Comment: I have 2 form, in the first i can use options like the first way you write but in in the second where i want use it not..
Your second way use class for symfony 2.8< , i use symfony3 and write like this RequestsType::class, i can't passing value into the form in this way new YourForm($options) ....

Comment: Try to use options resolver, I have completed the answer for symfony 3

Comment: I have founded the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027711/passing-data-to-buildform-in-symfony-2-8-3-0

Comment: ooh thx @sami boussacsou . i read yesterday this answer but not see last comment.. Now work thx