# Symfony2.8 get locale in form types

Tags: forms, symfony, locale, symfony-2.8

How can I get the locale in a typeform?

This is in my controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ConfiguratorClientType(), $configuratorClient);
```

I have this in my form builder:

```
->add('language',
    EntityType::class,
    array(
        'class' => 'CommonBundle:Language',
        'choice_label' => function ($language) {
            return $language->getName()[$locale];
        },
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control'
        )
    )
)
```

but I cant figure out how to get the locale in there.

Comment: do you want to get client locale or server locale?

Comment: for user's local check out [symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/translation/locale.html)

Comment: Client locale, I get it in the controller like this  => $locale = $request->getLocale();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register your form as a service and inject request stack:

```
services:
    form:
        class: YourBundle\Form\Type\YourType
        arguments: ["@request_stack"]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

and then get locale from your request.

More on request stack http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/request.html

or you can pass locale to your formType from your controller:

```
$locale = $request->getLocale();
$form = $this->createForm(new ConfiguratorClientType($locale), $configuratorClient);
```

and accept it in construct of your form.

Edit:

Contructor in the formtype:

```
private $locale = 'en';

   public function __construct($locale = 'en')
   {
       $this->locale = $locale;
   }
```

and then use the locale variable like this in the builder function:

```
$this->locale
```

Comment: How do I accept this in my form? I can't get it in the form. I tried with constructor and with OptionsResolvers but nothings works.

Comment: @Keutelvocht if you pass it like `new ConfiguratorClientType($locale)` you get it in your `__construct($locale)`

Comment: I get an error that i am missing a parameter. I must be missing something stupid.

Comment: @Keutelvocht it is always some stupid thing :D do you maybe use this form somewhere else? you can try doing `__construct($locale = null)`

Comment: I tried that also and $locale stays null so I still can't use it.

Comment: @Keutelvocht you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34035653 and pass it in to form options

Comment: I found the issue, i was using the passed variable wrong in the builder function. I completed you're answer  with my findings :P Thx!

Comment: @Keutelvocht glad to help :)

Answer (score 7):

If you have installed the `intl` module, you can use `\Locale::getDefault()` safely to get the current locale value. Even though the method infers default only, it can be changed through `\Locale::setDefault($locale)` just what Symfony does in `Request::setLocale` method.

Therefore, this should work for you:

```
return $language->getName()[\Locale::getDefault()];
```

**Update:**

However, it's not advisable to use this stateful class in your final app. Instead, you should adhere to the Dependency Inversion Principle, injecting the request stack service into your constructor, and retrieving the current locale from there (refer to the other answer for more details), which will be easier to test.